# How to SUM items in list separately?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a function that returns item types and the count items from a list.

I have:

```
def count_items(column_list):
    item_types = []
    count_items = []

    item_types = set(column_list)
    print(item_types)
    count_items = ????

    return item_types, count_items
```

The return fro `item_types` is:

```
{'', 'Female', 'Male'}
```

If I use `len` function to `count_items`, it will return the total of the three values, like `{1500}`, but I need them separately, like `{150, 550, 800}`
What should I use?

Comment: `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the counts only with list comprehension and set,

```
def count_items(column_list):

    item_types = set(column_list)

    return [column_list.count(item) for item in item_types]

column_list=['male','male','','','','female','male','female']


print(count_items(column_list))
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 3]
```

Or Both,

```
def count_items(column_list):

    item_types = set(column_list)

    return [[item,column_list.count(item)] for item in item_types]
```

Output:

```
[['', 3], ['male', 3], ['female', 2]]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that using `list.count()` here makes it O(N^2). Also it might be better to have `set(column_list)` outside the list comprehension, so it doesnt get generated on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list_of_items = ['a', 'a', 'b']

counter = Counter(my_list_of_items)

---> {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: It worked, but how can I return only the numbers? I am new in coding... struggling in a quiz :(

Comment: `list(counter.values())`

Comment: What @pylang said :)

Comment: @LeandroBaruch this is a far superior solution in terms of time-compexity. While it has the same asymptotic memory complexity as the accepted solution, the constant term should be significantly smaller, because `Counter` is a `dict` subclass and the latter is optimised for memory-consumption, while `set` is optimised for speed, but that speed gain is also a constant term, that is it doesn't matter in an asymptotically less efficient algorithm  (the accepted answer).